# the date picker the date does not change in the date text field

Tags: wicket

I have an issue with the date Picker in wicket and need help please:

Here is the code when was everything okay :

```
    private void addToDateFieldContainer() {
    DateField field = new ReservationDateField("validToDate");
    WebMarkupContainer container = new WebMarkupContainer("validToDateContainer");
    container.add(field);
    container.setVisible(configParams.isShowReservationToDate());
    add(container);
}
```

but I had a problem that the datetext field had a different id from the parent component, so I added some code

```
 private void addToDateFieldContainer() {
    DateField field = new ReservationDateField("validToDate"){
        @Override
        protected DateTextField newDateTextField(String id, PropertyModel dateFieldModel) {
            DateTextField dateTextField = DateTextField.forShortStyle(id, dateFieldModel);
            dateTextField.setMarkupId(this.getMarkupId());
            return dateTextField;
        }
    };
    WebMarkupContainer container = new WebMarkupContainer("validToDateContainer");
    container.add(field);
    container.setVisible(configParams.isShowReservationToDate());
    add(container);
}
```

now the date text id has the same id for the parent component, but it comes to a different problem :
when I press on the date picker the date does not change in the date text field

[here is an image about for the date picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsJIo.png)

Does anyone have a clue how I can overcome this issue?

Comment: Check for JavaScript errors in the browser's Dev Tools > Console

Comment: nothing in the JavaScript errors  
I think because I changed the id for the input component because when I return it to the original id it works fine, but then I have the old problem 
the label has id different than the input